# Which iOS jailbreak apps most closely implement an Android style notification system?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, notifications, android, cydia

Which iOS jailbreak apps implement a notifications system that most closely resembles Android's implementation?

Comment: I don't know of any, and if I don't know of any, then I'm sure it doesn't exist. I've read through the descriptions of almost every tweak in the default Cydia repositories and a plethora of others, too. I think it's because there's not enough people using iOS that want such a tweak. Most people are happy with the Apple's notification system.

Comment: I just got an idea - I'm going to post this question on a Cydia forum too and I'll report the results back here.  http://cydiaforums.com/f24/ios-jailbreak-apps-implement-notifications-system-thats-closest-androids-1612/#post5801

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon [SMS, Mail, Missed Calls Notifications In Status Bar | iPhone Cydia Tweak](http://theultralinx.com/2012/01/notifications-status-bar-iphone-cydia-tweak.html).